# passing a query string variable that is a keyword in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am working with an API that is posting to a URL.  One of the variables is is passing is called 'event'.  Since event is a keyword in C# my code is getting hung up on it.

```
public ActionResult Index(string event,string email, string category, string reason, string response, string type, string status)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

What is the workaround for this?

Comment: I believe the workaround is to use `@event` in place of `event`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keywords can usually not be used for argument names. However you can change your definition into:

```
public ActionResult Index(string @event, string email, ...) {
```

Answer (score 2):

From §2.4.2 Identifiers of the C#4 spec:

> The prefix “@” enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a ***verbatim identifier***. Use of the @ prefix for identifiers that are not keywords is permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of style.

This doesn't apply just to other languages, but also when using Reflection from C#, which is (I assume) what MVC does. So your method should be:

```
public ActionResult Index(string @event, string email, string category, string reason,
                          string response, string type, string status)
{
    return View();
}
```